# background image url linking issue

Tags: html, css

Please take a look of web Application and gives me some tips to link with image file. as i wanted to linked somehow e.g.
in

```
 myHtml.html
 <div id = "myID" style="background:url('/imageFolder/myImage1.jpg')" > </div>

 Web Application(myProject)
     |
     |_____htmlFolder
     |         |
     |         |_______myHtml.html  // i have to link a image file url in this page from other folder 
     | 
     |_____Image Folderr
               |
               |_______myimage1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this, it will work: 

<div id = "myID" style="background-image:url('../imageFolder/myImage1.jpg')" > </div>
```